# Angular - Ng Multiselect if statement

Tags: angular

I can't seem to figure out how to change different booleans when I select an item out of the NG Multiselect dropdown list.

in my app.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.dropdownList = [
    { item_id: 1, item_text: 'option 1' },
    { item_id: 2, item_text: 'option 2'},
    { item_id: 3, item_text: 'option 3'},
    { item_id: 4, item_text: 'etc' },
    { item_id: 5, item_text: 'etc' }
  ];
  this.dropdownSettings = {
    singleSelection: false,
    idField: 'item_id',
    textField: 'item_text',
    selectAllText: 'Selecteer allemaal',
    unSelectAllText: 'Verwijder selectie',
    itemsShowLimit: 3,
    allowSearchFilter: true
  };
}
onItemSelect(item: any) {
  console.log(item);
}
onSelectAll(items: any) {
  console.log(items);
}
}
```

Above code works fine. When I select an item it gets logged in the console

What I am aiming to achieve is when item_id 1 is checked, set a boolean to true.
Something like this (but does not work):

```
onItemSelect(item: any) {
if(this.dropdownList.idField == 1) {
  this.option1boolean = true
}
if (this.dropdownList.idField == 2) {
  this.option2boolean = true
}
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use item.item_id in place of this.dropdownList.idField

```js
public onItemSelect(item: any) {
  if (item.item_id === 1) {
    this.option1boolean = true;
  }
  if (item.item_id === 2) {
    this.option2boolean = true;
  }
}
```